# How to update the text / innerHTML of multiple span elements returned by getElementsByClassName?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to get values from input fields put in to span elements. The input fields each have an id, those are in the array "tekstvelden". The spans each have a class, those are in the array "spans"

```
function getValue(elementId) {
  return document.getElementById(elementId).value;
};

function schrijfVerhaal() {
  var tekstvelden = ['znw', 'bvn', 'bvn2', 'held', 'prinses'];
  var spans = ['znwT', 'bvnT', 'bvn2T', 'heldT', 'prinsesT'];

  tekstvelden.forEach(function(item, index) {
    var inhoudVeld = getValue(item);
    var spanClass = spans[index];
    document.getElementsByClassName(spanClass).innerHTML = inhoudVeld;
  });
};
```

Comment: getElement **s** ByClassName() returns a collection, not a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an  `HTMLCollection` of found elements. If you want to update every element of the collection, then loop through the elements and update the `innerHTML`

```js
function getValue(elementId) {
  return document.getElementById(elementId).value;
};

var tekstvelden = ['znw', 'bvn', 'bvn2'];
var spans = ['znwT', 'bvnT', 'bvn2T'];

tekstvelden.forEach(function(item, index) {
  var inhoudVeld = getValue(item);
  var spanClass = spans[index];
  
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(spanClass)
  
  for(let e of elements)
    e.innerHTML = inhoudVeld;
});
```

```html
<input id="znw" value="10" />
<input id="bvn" value="20" />
<input id="bvn2" value="30" />

<br>
<span class="znwT"></span>
<span class="bvnT"></span>
<span class="bvn2T"></span>

<br>
<span class="znwT"></span>
<span class="bvnT"></span>
<span class="bvn2T"></span>
```

Comment: That only runs the innerHTML on the first <span>  though, I have multiple.

Comment: Then you need to loop through the collection. Updated the answer. Click on `Run code snippet` to test it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.getElementsByClassName(spanClass)[0].innerHTML`

If you want to do it for all of them:

```
for (let i of document.getElementsByClassName(spanClass)){
   i.innerHTML = ...;
}
```